# Percorrer variavel tipo array php

Tags: php, array, echo

Tenho uma variável $array que contém valores array que foram recebidos de um `JSON.stringify(venc)`

```
[
{"Nº da Parc":"1","Data do pagamento":"06/04/2017","valor a pagar":"R$ 50,00"},
{"Nº da Parc":"2","Data do pagamento":"06/05/2017","valor a pagar":"R$ 50,00"},
{"Nº da Parc":"3","Data do pagamento":"06/06/2017","valor a pagar":"R$ 50,00"},
{"Nº da Parc":"4","Data do pagamento":"06/07/2017","valor a pagar":"R$ 50,00"},
{"Nº da Parc":"5","Data do pagamento":"06/08/2017","valor a pagar":"R$ 50,00"}
]
```

Consegui exibir apenas com o `echo $array;` .

Como faço pra eu percorrer essa variável?

Tentei usar o

```
foreach($array as $d){
  echo $d;
}
```

e nada exibe

e ao tentar usar `$arr = json_decode($array);` o arquivo php dá erro, 
Não dá mensagem, apenas fica vermelho no debugger do chrome

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em PHP, arrays associativos também são definidos entre `[]`, não `{}`, fora que não é usado `:` na atribuição e sim `=>`. Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/GKCL/0)

Comment: é porque esses valores vieram do JSON.stringify(venc); ai no php estou querendo percorrê-los

Comment: Mas se está chegando desta forma no PHP, você precisa antes converter de JSON para array. Para isso, existe a função [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: toda vez que faço `$var = json_decode($array)` dá erro no arquivo php. Usando `var_dump(json_decode($array)` funciona, mas eu gostaria de percorrer para mostrar de forma organizada. Como se converte json para array?

Comment: Com essa função. Edita sua pergunta e posta todo seu código. Está complicado entender o que você está fazendo. Posta junto o erro que dá.

Comment: mas o arquivo apenas fica vermelho naquele debugger do chrome e não diz que erro é

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tentei desta forma e parece que funciona

```
$json= '[
{"Nº da Parc":"1","Data do pagamento":"06/04/2017","valor a pagar":"R$ 50,00"},
{"Nº da Parc":"2","Data do pagamento":"06/05/2017","valor a pagar":"R$ 50,00"},
{"Nº da Parc":"3","Data do pagamento":"06/06/2017","valor a pagar":"R$ 50,00"},
{"Nº da Parc":"4","Data do pagamento":"06/07/2017","valor a pagar":"R$ 50,00"},
{"Nº da Parc":"5","Data do pagamento":"06/08/2017","valor a pagar":"R$ 50,00"}
]';



$data = json_decode($json);
foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
        echo '  ' . $value->{'Nº da Parc'} . "<br>";
        echo '  ' . $value->{'Data do pagamento'} . "<br>";
        echo '  ' . $value->{'valor a pagar'} . "<br>";

}
```

Comment: é porque esses valores vieram do JSON.stringify(venc); desse jeito ai no php estou querendo percorrê-los

Comment: Como assim não dá para usar assim como coloquei agora?

Comment: é porque o Json já envia daquele jeito

Comment: Pronto editei tente assim

Comment: Bingoooo!! Exatamente isso! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Isso se dá devido a não capacidade do php trabalhar diretamente com Json. Você precisa converte-lo para uma array associativa através do método `json_decode`.

Basta passar a string contendo o json para o método e ele retornará um array:

```
$resultado = json_decode($json);
```

dando um var_dump você verá que o resultado é um array associativo, podendo ser percorrido através de um `foreach`

Comment: Não querendo ser chato, mas no que sua resposta acrescenta à discussão que já não foi dito na resposta acima?

Comment: Eu explico o motivo de não funcionar.

Comment: mas é uma informação importante