# Como percorrer um array de objetos acessando cada elemento do array com PHP

Tags: php

```
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 130627
                [avatar] => 
                [first_name] => Prii
                [last_name] => Camargo
                [email] => teste@gmail.com
                [name] => Sorocaba
                [ref_code] => pckystxa
                [banned] => 0
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 130583
                [avatar] => 
                [first_name] => Maicon
                [last_name] => França
                [email] => teste@gmail.com
                [name] => Sorocaba
                [ref_code] => mfm73pn0
                [banned] => 0
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 130540
                [avatar] => 
                [first_name] => Rafael
                [last_name] => 0
                [email] => teste@gmail.com
                [name] => Sorocaba
                [ref_code] => repakms
                [banned] => 0
            )
```

....

Comment: Relacionada: [Quais são as formas de iterar um array em PHP (sem foreach)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81446/5878)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Percorrer variavel tipo array php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188351/percorrer-variavel-tipo-array-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O PHP fornece uma maneira de definir objetos para que seja possível iterar por uma lista de items, como, por exemplo, a instrução [foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php). Por padrão, todas as propriedades visíveis serão utilizadas para a iteração.

**Exemplo #1 Iteração simples de objetos**

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    public $var1 = 'value 1';
    public $var2 = 'value 2';
    public $var3 = 'value 3';

    protected $protected = 'protected var';
    private   $private   = 'private var';

    function iterateVisible() {
       echo "MyClass::iterateVisible:\n";
       foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
           print "$key => $value\n";
       }
    }
}

$class = new MyClass();

foreach($class as $key => $value) {
    print "$key => $value\n";
}
echo "\n";


$class->iterateVisible();

?>
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir:

```
var1 => value 1
var2 => value 2
var3 => value 3

MyClass::iterateVisible:
var1 => value 1
var2 => value 2
var3 => value 3
protected => protected var
private => private var
```

Como a saída mostra, o foreach passou por cada uma das variáveis visíveis que podem ser acessadas.

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.iterations.php

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `foreach` ele funciona somente em `arrays` e `objetos`, e emitirá um erro ao tentar usá-lo em uma variável com um tipo de dado diferente ou em uma variável não inicializada.

```
foreach ($meu_array as $chave => $item_objeto){
    echo "Chave do Array: ".$chave."<br>";
    echo "id: ".$item_objeto->id;
    echo "first_name: ".$item_objeto->first_name;
    // Assim por diante ...
}
```

[Documentação *foreach*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)